# How to add css file for controls using string builder in c#?

Tags: c#, css, stringbuilder

First I created the control using string  builder, Form.cs

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<ul>");
for (int i=0; i<500; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(string.Format("<li>{0}</li>",i));
    }

    LinkButton lnkBtn = new LinkButton();
        lnkBtn.ID = "lnkBtnSubmit";
        lnkBtn.Text = "Submit";

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
    {
        using (HtmlTextWriter tw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            lnkBtn.RenderControl(tw);
        }
    }

sb.Append("</ul>");

return sb.ToString();
```

I want to give style to this control, but I don't know how?or Is it even possible? to add css for control in .cs file.

Comment: `sb.Append(string.Format("<li>{0}</li>",i));` = `sb.AppendFormat("<li>{0}</li>",i)`.  You can either add inline styles to the `ul` and `li` or you could just give the ul and li a class and then style them in the main stylesheet for the site

Comment: Your comment below makes it sound like you want to apply a style to the button.  You should update the question, since there are other things here one could apply a style to.

Comment: I put that question because, I want to  know that is there way to apply style dynamically, not inline or header styling. applying style to button was specific example for that.

Answer (score 0):

You should to declare links to css files in `<head>` section. So user can add style/style bundle in layout template manualy or by using helper method.

In another way you can use inline styles.

Comment: no no, I know abt that, I want to  add  .button class from my css file to lnkBtn.

Answer (score 0):

You got two valid ways:

First, add a 'style' - tag to your control.
[General information on this.](http://www.pageresource.com/dhtml/csstut2.htm)

Second:

Declare the style for it in the main css file of the site.
It'll just grab its data from there.

Answer (score 0):

The `LinkButton` class has a `Style` property where you can apply styling directly to the element, and a `CssClass` property to apply a css class.  From your comment above, it sounds like you want:

```
lnkBtn.CssClass = "button";
```